# Validation on custom field

Tags: custom-fields

Have a custom field on Contact called as 'Employee ID #'. We want to restrict user/staff from submitting the form from adding more than 6 digits. How to add validation on custom field to accept up-to 6 digits only? i.e between 0 to 999999.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this

1. Implementing [hook_civicrm_validateForm()](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) hook via extension/module/plugin to add php code .

code:

```
function MYMODULE_civicrm_validateForm($formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors) {
  // 12 is the custom field id
  // inspect on form to get the exact field name
  if (!empty($fields['custom_12'])) {
    preg_match("/^[0-9]{0,6}$/", $fields['custom_12'], $matches);
    if (empty($matches)) {
      $errors['custom_12'] = ts('Error message.');
    }
  }
}
```

2. Implementing [hook_civicrm_buildForm()](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook to add js via extension/module/plugin or from theme function

code:

```
function MYMODULE_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  // Replace the FORM_NAME with Form name
  if ($formName == 'FORM_NAME') {
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScript(
      "CRM.$(function($) {
        // on custom field blur or change OR submit button hit
        // Check if the value in text is upto 6 digit using match()
        // display error using CRM.alert(ts('Error message'), ts('Error'));
      });"
    );
  }
}
```

3. You can add [HTML5 patter](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)n to do the validation. Civi provides attributes to be added into Custom field, however this is not visible through GUI, you can use mysql query or api3 or api4 explorer to add.

Mysql code:

```
-- Add attribute for custom field id 12
UPDATE civicrm_custom_field SET attributes = ' pattern="^[0-9]{0,6}$" ' WHERE id = 12;
```

API3:

[image]

API4:

[image]

Comment: Wow you went all out on this one. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the field a dropdown list or autocomplete with a million option choices (ha ha! I'm joking. Partly - it *would* technically work...)

Comment: a good answer for this crazy xmas period

Answer (score 2):

If this was Drupal and you were happy doing this via a Webform then webform_validation might be your friend - and could potentially enforce 'unique' too if that mattered